# Cant find the ID mapping using json4s

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I am receiving the following json into my code and since i'm new to scala I'm struggling to get the issue resolved

This is the json:

```
{"id":1486363,"doc":{"v": "1", "x": "1", "y": "1", "z": "1", "lux": "0", "rssi": "440", "alarm": "0", "magnet": "3", "agesent": "540227616", "datetime": "2017/11/24 15:38:22.402902", "movement": "65535", "readerId": 75, "sensorId": "3217003", "uniqueName": "hive", "locationCounter": "0", "locationSensorId": "0"},"created_at":"2017-11-18T10:00:00","sensorId":null,"readerId":null}
```

I have this case class for the json to be cast to

```
case class SensorRead(id: String, doc: JObject, created_at: Timestamp)
```

And this is the code that is causing the issue

```
val json = parse(not.getParameter) // json 
val prod = json.noNulls.extract[SensorRead]
```

And this is the error

```
No usable value for id
Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String
org.json4s.package$MappingException: No usable value for id
Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String
```

**Edit**

Below is the formatter for the timestamp - i'm also using the json4s library - "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.5.3",

```
      implicit val formats = new DefaultFormats {
        override def dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
      }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the value inside the variable `json` is what you've shown us? Also what is `Timestamp` and what is the implicit `Formats` that you have?

Comment: Can you add more details like which json parsing library are you using and what is the structure of Timestamp?

Comment: if you are using play json library, have a look: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-json/

Comment: i am using json4s-  i tagged it in to the question. I have updated the question with the timestamp parser

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `id` as an Int , so try this: (also you might need to write `createdAt` )

```
case class SensorRead(id: Int, doc: JObject, created_at: Timestamp)
```

Comment: i'm still getting the same error for this- No usable value for id
Did not find value which can be converted into int
org.json4s.package$MappingException: No usable value for id
Did not find value which can be converted into int